# HTML Table - Sum of ( value * coefficient ) JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, sum, html-table

I have built an HTML Table, and I want to calculate in it's last column, the sum of some values multiplied by their coefficients.

I know that I was very terrible in this explanation :D that's why I've attached the picture below to be the clearest possible :

[image: Jquery sum coefficient]

I want in the "average score" column to calculate the sum of (qty * score ) of each column in the same row,

Please find below the HTML code for the table :

```
<pre>
 <table id="kitchen">
   <tr>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 1</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 2</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 3</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 4</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 5</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Variety Score</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Average Score</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="avg_score">Score</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="qty">10</td>
     <td class="score">7.5</td>
     <td class="qty">20</td>
     <td class="score">6</td>
     <td class="qty">212</td>
     <td class="score">9.2</td>
     <td class="qty">9</td>
     <td class="score">7.9</td>
     <td class="qty">1</td>
     <td class="score">7.5</td>
     <td class="variety_score">10</td>
     <td class="avg_score">7.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="qty">100</td>
     <td class="score">4.5</td>
     <td class="qty">15</td>
     <td class="score">5</td>
     <td class="qty">22</td>
     <td class="score">9.2</td>
     <td class="qty">18</td>
     <td class="score">3.5</td>
     <td class="qty">90</td>
     <td class="score">9.5</td>
     <td class="variety_score">10</td>
     <td class="avg_score">7.5</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Are there a fixed number of batches? 5? Also, how are you putting this table information together?

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, it starts with `$("#kitchen tr:gt(1)").each()` to loop over the table rows except the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for what you want to do. I added an extra `class data` to the rows that contained the data.

```js
$('.data').each(function(index, tr) {
    var lines = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
 var sum = 0;
    var n = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i+=2) {
     sum = sum + lines[i]*lines[i + 1];
        n = n + lines[i]*1;
        
    }
 $(this).find('td:last').html(sum/n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
 <table id="kitchen">
   <tr>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 1</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 2</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 3</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 4</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="Batch">Batch 5</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Variety Score</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Average Score</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="Item_Score">Score</th>
     <th class="Qty">Qty</th>
     <th class="avg_score">Score</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="data">
     <td class="qty">10</td>
     <td class="score">7.5</td>
     <td class="qty">20</td>
     <td class="score">6</td>
     <td class="qty">212</td>
     <td class="score">9.2</td>
     <td class="qty">9</td>
     <td class="score">7.9</td>
     <td class="qty">1</td>
     <td class="score">7.5</td>
     <td class="variety_score">10</td>
     <td class="avg_score"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class = "data">
     <td class="qty">100</td>
     <td class="score">4.5</td>
     <td class="qty">15</td>
     <td class="score">5</td>
     <td class="qty">22</td>
     <td class="score">9.2</td>
     <td class="qty">18</td>
     <td class="score">3.5</td>
     <td class="qty">90</td>
     <td class="score">9.5</td>
     <td class="variety_score">10</td>
     <td class="avg_score"></td>
  </tr>
```